# <xs:openContent> causing error: 'invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often'

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I am trying to figure out how to design my XSD to allow elements from any other namespace, and these other elements having elements from my namespace.

I learned from examples and discussions that `<openContent>` is the right thing to do so. But for some reasons, I don't get my schema valid. So I tried from scratch, based upon *[Example 12-40 Defining an interleaved open content model](http://www.datypic.com/books/defxmlschema/chapter12.html)*:

```xml
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning">
    <xs:element name="product" type="OpenProductType" vc:minVersion="1.1" />
    <xs:complexType name="OpenProductType">
        <xs:openContent>
            <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" />
        </xs:openContent>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="number" type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

VSCode complains about line 6 (`<xs:openContent>`):

> *s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'OpenProductType' is invalid. Element 'openContent' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.*

Why is this invalid?

Setting the XSD version to 1.1 did not solve this.

Changing the order of `<xs:openContent>` and `<xs:sequence>` has no effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xs:openContent` requires XSD 1.1

> Setting the XSD version to 1.1 did not solve this.

Changing the version declaration in the XSD does not change the capabilities of the XSD processor you're using.  The error you're receiving indicates that you're using an XSD 1.0 processor.  Upgrade to a XSD 1.1 processor if you wish to use XSD 1.1 constructs such as `xs:openContent`.

Comment: That's a point. I'm using the Red Hat XML extension for VSCode. In an issue on GutHub it is stated, that they do not support XSD 1.1. The blame is on me for assuming the already ten yeas old W3C recomendation would by a standard by now.
However, I find it confusing that all of the online XML/XSD validators I've tried (and I've put this in almost every validator I could find) all thrown the same error on my XSD.
Well, I guess I need to find another solution. :(

Comment: @Suppenhuhn79: It is indeed unfortunate that XSD 1.1 is not more widely supported.  For professional development, I use and recommend [Saxonica's products](https://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml) which support XSD 1.1 and all of the latest XML-related standards.

Comment: @Suppenhuhn79, the (semi official) Xerces Java online validator (supporting XSD 1.1 if you select it) is at https://www.softwarebytes.org/xmlvalidation/. You can of course also download the XSD 1.1 version of Xerces from the Apache Xerces Java site or probably find it on Maven. My XML workbench at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/, if you do XSD validation, also does (somehow experimental) XSD 1.1 validation using the Python xmlschema library cross-compiled to webassembly.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Thanks for the [softwarebytes.org/xmlvalidation](https://www.softwarebytes.org/xmlvalidation/) link and thanks for creating and making available online your [XML Workbench](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/).  Very useful!